# Why doesn't my Dynamics CRM On-Line jQuery oData query work?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a web page that needs to obtain information from Dynamics CRM2011 on-line using jQuery. As a test, I've just tried to retrieve all of the accounts from a test system. I've used some code that I've tested within the CRM product, and it works.

When I try to run the same jQuery code in a separate web page that is not on the CRM domain it doesn't work (no transport) so I added the $.support.cors = true line to allow cross-site scripting. Now when it runs it pops up a dialog box asking for credentials. However, when I enter my credentials for CRM on-line, it doesn't accept them. After three attempts I get the error, "unauthorized".

Can anyone help?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var request = "https://myorganisation.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet";
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: request,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: 
        function (XMLHttpRequest) 
        { 
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        },
    success: 
        function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) 
        {
            var result = data.d.results[0];
            alert('Success');
            alert(result);
            alert(result.Name);
        },
    error: 
        function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        { 
            alert(textStatus); 
            alert(errorThrown); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oData endpoint doesn't support cross site requests.  It is designed to only support authentication from within the CRM application using either Silverlight or JavaScript Web Resources.

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i think i met something like that some time ago 
the function work fine but the request can't update the values of the variables with  the success function right away

that's why i  use the `always()` function instead of success to update the variables with the received values

the new always function = the old completed function which fires after request is completed

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> from this page :
>   Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how those would be used (I'm not a jQuery developer). Would I just remove the success and error values, put the error stuff in the fail() function and the success stuff in the always() bit? Can I leave the beforeSend: section and everything else the same (the request header setting is requried for CRM).

Comment: ...if so, I tried that and I get the same result. I'm asked repeatedly for credentials but they don't work :(